# Angularjs give focus to the window after login

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am using angular, .NET, MVC, VS2015.

I am using social login on my website. When signing in user gets redirected from main window to login window. After successful login, it stays on login page. I would like the user to return to main page.
(on the main page, script is being trigered in time intervals and checks for login cookie (while user is on the login page). When cookie is there, it redirects to user page).

What I have already tried is give focus with $window object on the user page (when user is already redirected), but nothing happens. User is still on the login page.

```
$document.ready(function () {

    $window.focus();
})
```

Comment: $document.ready(function () {

    $window.focus();
}) Are you using jquery or angular js, please be clear

Comment: I am using angular. $window is injected into my controller.

Comment: Have you tried $location.path ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27787498/redirection-after-login-angularjs , see if this link helps you.

Comment: Is it possible to redirect and close the window?

Comment: You just have to redirect , "closing window" - IMHO it's just not AngularJS thing.

Answer (score 1):

Angular is a Single Page App, meaning it does not refresh the entire page like traditional web applications. You must use a type of routing to change from say, your login page to your main page.

You can use that in two ways using AngularJS:

1. ngRoute that provides you with routes to change from login to the main https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/service/$route
2. UI Router (more advanced) that provides you with state based management, where you can for instance change from one state (login) to another (main) https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router